# Why npm start is not working and giving the following error messages:

Tags: npm

I have one question regarding npm. Whenever I start `npm`, it gives the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pomodorclock@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pomodorclock@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Comment: What command do you use?

Comment: npm start@albert

Comment: Do you use the command in a project folder or where? And the project folder contains `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to run `npm install` before you can build the package. After you can use `npm start`.

Comment: did that @ albert